# Crop and scale a video takes significant amount of time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a 5 seconds .mp4 video 1280x720 and I want to scale, crop and rotate it:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex scale=1138:640, crop=640:640:249:0, transpose=1 -threads 3 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -y output.mp4`

And it takes about 13 seconds to perform this operations on a 5 sec video using my phone. Is there any way to speed it up? Losing the quality is acceptable if it's the only way.

Here is output:

```
    ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep  6 2015 00:45:52 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/mike/Downloads/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/original0.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isommp42
creation_time   : 2015-09-13 19:12:47
Duration: 00:00:05.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67205 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 65036 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 29.91 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2015-09-13 19:12:47
handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2015-09-13 19:12:47
handler_name    : SoundHandle
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] using SAR=1462/1463
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/processed0.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isommp42
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x640 [SAR 10233:10240 DAR 10233:10240], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2015-09-13 19:12:47
handler_name    : SoundHandle
encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
transpose (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   14 fps= 13 q=26.0 size=     124kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=1015.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   25 fps= 16 q=26.0 size=     257kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=2098.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   30 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=     319kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate=1699.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   34 fps= 13 q=26.0 size=     371kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=1514.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   44 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=     495kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=2021.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   55 fps= 15 q=26.0 size=     635kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=2594.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   61 fps= 15 q=26.0 size=     711kB time=00:00:02.32 bitrate=2505.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   64 fps= 13 q=26.0 size=     747kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=2033.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   74 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=     867kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=2360.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   83 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=     979kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=2667.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   92 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1091kB time=00:00:03.02 bitrate=2951.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=   94 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1116kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=2280.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  104 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1240kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=2533.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  114 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1363kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate=2784.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  123 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1465kB time=00:00:04.03 bitrate=2976.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  125 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1490kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=2435.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  134 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1605kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=2623.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  143 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1715kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=2802.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  151 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1815kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=2965.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  158 fps= 14 q=26.0 size=    1903kB time=00:00:05.31 bitrate=2934.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
frame=  160 fps= 14 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1984kB time=00:00:05.35 bitrate=3035.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0
video:1898kB audio:80kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.292008%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size: 16321
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] frame P:159   Avg QP:25.93  size: 12118
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] mb P  I16..4: 58.6%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 33.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 7.6%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 72.9% 10.6% 0.0% inter: 43.7% 15.5% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 21% 12% 55% 12%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 17% 22%  9%
[libx264 @ 0xb5829c00] kb/s:2914.67
```

Comment: You are using a phone. That is a device typically designed for low power usage (and typically low CPU speed as a result). Try running it on a normal computer and things  will be much faster.

Comment: You're right, it's not the best device to do video-processing. But I'm wondering if there's a way to make things faster in terms of FFmpeg, like use some "magic" parameter. Probably there's a specific filter that combines all these operations together.

Comment: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/496808/user496808 and http://superuser.com/users/496818/user1049280.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to this question.

Comment: *"takes significant amount of time"* -- You're trying to perform an operation that requires a lot of computational power, as well as a lot of I/O operations (i.e. time).  Before each frame can be scaled, cropped and rotated, the video has to be uncompressed and decoded, and prior to storage it has to be encoded and compressed.  Your operation is taking less than 3 times the time length of the video.  That is not too bad for a phone!

Comment: It used to take even more time but then I added "-threads 3" and it helped a lot. So there's no more magic like this? :)

Comment: `[libx264] using cpu capabilities: none!` is usually not a good sign. I'm not familiar with ARM, but I'd guess ARMv6, ARMv8, and/or NEON should be expected depending on the hardware. Optimal thread selection should be automatic, so `-threads 3` may be sub-optimal.

Comment: x264 has both NEON and, in the latest releases, armv8 NEON support. Unless your phone is very old, you should be able to take advantage of those. Make sure to compile the latest libx264 and the latest FFmpeg with the correct build configuration to enable them !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using crop before scale. Obviously you also need to modify the scaling and cutting parameters.

Comment: Thank you, sir! It gave me 25% boost! Perhaps you know the answer for my another ffmpeg-related question? http://superuser.com/questions/972568/concat-videos-after-applying-filters